# How can I build a Type that has all the properties from an array of Types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Say I have two types (just for example, I need something generic)

```
type TypeA = { propA: string};
type TypeB = { propB: number};
```

I would like to write a Generic type that would allow me to do something like this

```
type ABMerge = ArrayMerge<[TypeA,TypeB]>

// ABMerge would look like { propA: string, propB: number }
```

I've tried using generic and conditional types, but I can't figure out how to "iterate" over my Generic type array.

Comment: Maybe the type intersection `&` ?

Comment: Don't think you can accomplish this with an array type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to first 'overlay' all array elements onto one, using `T[number]`.
That gives us a union of all types (like `TypeA | TypeB`).

Because you want to have an intersection type (`TypeA & TypeB`), we can then convert that union into an intersection using the nifty trick in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/2854696).

Full example:

```js
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
    (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never

type ArrayMerge<T extends Array<any>> = UnionToIntersection<T[number]>;

// Test it:
type TypeA = { propA: number };
type TypeB = { propB: string };

const ab: ArrayMerge<[TypeA, TypeB]> = {
    propA: 42,
    propB: "x",
};

ab.propA; // number
ab.propB; // string
```

Check it out in the [playground](http://%20https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwCpIJJ2BATgZwgGNhk4AeGAPigF4BYAKAEgAKGKCADxzgBN8UAIZwQUAPxRWAawBcsAJR0aANyQI+UeXAgq8S7rwFSZ8hHABmeKBiW1V6vkskYtUHXtxMmoSFACCuLhCIACyeADmEOSonDwQ-IKBwSDkIiBUNLSwiCjoWDgExKQoMQDacACuALYARngAulQA3N6MAPTtUKgQ+MBQCMCyPuDQqKP+dFAA3lBguEhg-to19bhQAL6tjL5jowBCU7Pzi-vyfbjmEZvbTEQofcK18skh4bhR5GXjkP4ANN0Dk0jkxmCclvIACwAJj+oPBZygACIuEi4Ywtm0hLUAHTg-zNKCddyrPBMbF4hZgfaE4kXK5AA).

Comment: Thank you very much Martin, this is exactly what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the type intersection operator `&` in Typescript:

```
type A = { propA: number };
type B = { propB: string };

type AB = A & B;

const ab: AB = {
    propA: 42,
    propB: "hello, world",
};
```

[See on the playground](http://type%20A%20=%20%7B%20propA:%20number%20%7D;%20type%20B%20=%20%7B%20propB:%20string%20%7D;%20%20type%20AB%20=%20A%20&%20B;%20%20const%20ab:%20AB%20=%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20propA:%2042,%20%20%20%20%20propB:%20%22hello,%20world%22,%20%7D;)

Comment: Sorry, I think my question didn't make it clear enough, but I don't always know the types A and B, thats why I need something more generic

Comment: @RamaRivera You don't need to know the types A and B in advance. You can use `A & B` just like you would write `a + b` without knowing about a and b.